# Estimating and measuring CloudKit database usage

Tags: icloud, cloudkit

CloudKit has some pretty stringent [data limits](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/cloudkit-storage/), restricting to 50MB of database storage plus 1MB per user, with 250KB/day in database bandwidth plus 5KB per user.

To find out how CloudKit incorporates database structure and protocol overheads into these numbers, is there a dashboard I'm able to look at to see the size of a record or table, or the amount of bandwidth consumed?

Comment: What was your final solution / course of action on this?  I too am surprised that the shared database access is slow low, it seems more like a typo than a workable limit.

Comment: @chrisco Sorry for the late response. We ended up abandoning CloudKit due to these limitations. We contacted Apple asking for clarification and didn't get any response back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't any way to view usage statistics in the CloudKit dashboard.

Note though that the data limits mentioned are just for the public database. If you use the private database the use is counted against the individual user's quota (every iCloud account gets 5GB of storage free and users can pay for additional storage), and the transfer limits are high enough that you shouldn't run into them in practice.

Comment: Great info. Do you have a source for the data being counted against their 5GB?

We're wanting to use CloudKit for syncing a database across multiple devices, so we'd need much more than 5KB per day in transfers, unless I'm misunderstanding that limit.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKContainer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CKContainer under the "Public and Private Databases" section: "The data in a public database counts against the iCloud storage quota of the app that owns the container. That data does not count against the storage quota of any single user. Data in the private database counts against the user’s iCloud storage quota."

Comment: The Advanced CloudKit talk at WWDC also mentions this: http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/231?q=cloudkit (search for "limits")